# Haskell divide Double by Int

Tags: haskell

I have the following piece of code, the problem is that I try to divide a `Double` by an `Int`

```
factorial :: Int -> Int
factorial 0 = 1
factorial e = e * (factorial e-1)

sumX :: Double -> Int -> Double
sumX x 0 = (x^0) / (factorial 0)
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: "cast" it to double. google casting.

Comment: @daredevil err no ... Haskell does not *cast* ;) (but you gonna find a great webcast if you do)

Comment: Chris gave you the answers you need so let me ask you a question: why would you do `(x^0) / (factorial 0)` when it's just gonna be `1/1 = 1` anyway?

Comment: @Carsten Beucause this is the base case of a recurive function and I want to be very clear

Comment: @IonutCosminMihai what is `y = x^0` when `x = 0`? From a mathematical standpoint both `y = 0` and `y = 1` are valid choices.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, it turns out that one of those choices is considerably more convenient than the other (1, I think), but using that convention certainly doesn't make the code clearer!

Comment: @epsilonhalbe x is never 0 in my problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One problem is that you have incorrectly parenthesized your factorial function. You should write

```
factorial e = e * factorial (e - 1)
```

Secondly, you can use the `fromIntegral` function to convert any integral type (an instance of the `Integral` class) to any numeric type (an instance of the `Num` class)

```
sumX x 0 = x ^ 0 / fromIntegral (factorial 0)
```